ReactJS + JSX: How to iterate/render an array with some conditional formatting?
basically I need to generate a
<div class=row></div>

every 3rd record. how can I do this?
Some info:

using the sample code below, I'm getting an "unexpected token" error
HTML renders fine if I remove the getReminder calls
instead of "return index & divisor", I tried "return 1" and I get the same error

this is my sample JSX
const cars = ['Saab', 'Volvo', 'BMW', 'Toyota', 'Honda', 'Subaru']

export default function App() {
    const getRemainder = function (index, divisor) {
        return index % divisor
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="container-fluid">
                {cars.map((x, index) => (
                    {getRemainder(index, 3) == 0 && <div className='row'>}
                    <h4>
                        car: {x} | index: {index}
                    </h4>
                    {getRemainder(index, 3) == 2 && </div>}
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

this woud be my ideal rendered HTML using the sample code above
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">Saab</div>
        <div class="col">Volvo</div>
        <div class="col">BMW</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col">Toyota</div>
       <div class="col">Honda</div>
       <div class="col">Subaru</div>
   </div>
</div>


you cant conditionally add opening/closing html, it must be a valid XML element.

@LãNgọcHải what options are available to me then? thanks

I suggest you chunk your array, then map the chunked array (one map for the outer array, and then another for the inner items).

You are getting

"unexpected token" error

because  {getRemainder(index, 3) == 0 && <div className='row'>} is invalid JSX, the element div should have a closing tag.
You can achieve the required output by slicing the array into an array of arrays of the three items.
Here is the updated code that achieve the required output. I also abstracted the row into a separate component.
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Honda", "Subaru"];

const transformedCars = [];
for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i += 3) {
  transformedCars.push(cars.slice(i, i + 3));
}

export default function App() {
  const getRemainder = function (index, divisor) {
    return index % divisor;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        {transformedCars.map((cars, index) => (
          <CarsRow key={index} cars={cars} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

const CarsRow = ({ cars }) => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      {cars.map((car, index) => (
        <h4>
          car: {car} | index: {index}
        </h4>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};


JSX are not strings. Therefore you can't pretend you are concatenating strings. You are instead building a tree of objects.
Your bug is here:
{getRemainder(index, 3) == 0 && <div className='row'>}

This should throw an error since when JSX processes this expression it will find the div to be unclosed.
This is also invalid:
{getRemainder(index, 3) == 2 && </div>}

The div has no matching opening tag.
What you can do instead is refactor the list creation logic into its own function:
const splitGroup = (items, columns) => {
    let group = [];
    let i = [...items];

    while (i.length > 0) {
        group.push(
        <div class="row">
            i.splice(0, columns).map(x => {
                return <div class="col">{x}</div>
            })
        </div>
        )
    }

    return group;
}

then simply do:
return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
        {splitGroup(cars, 3)}
    </div>
)

Alternative code
If you're not familiar with .splice() you can do the same with traditional for loops:
const splitGroup = (items, columns) => {
    let group = [];
    let i = [...items];

    while (i.length > 0) {
        let row = [];

        for (let x=0; x<columns && i.length > 0; x++) {
            row.push(<div class="col">{i.shift()}</div>
        }

        group.push(
            <div class="row">{row}</div>
        )
    }

    return group;
}


Don't use methods like Array.splice without first making a copy of the array or Array.shift unless you like mutating references in your React code.

@DrewReese Nice catch. Code updated
